# Kotlin receiver type mismatch error when using extention function

Tags: kotlin

if I have a list

```
val nums: IntArray

private val positionValuePairs: List<Pair<Int, Int>>

init {
  positionValuePairs = nums.mapIndexedNotNull { index: Int, value: Int -> 
    if (value != 0) index to value else null
  }
}
```

explain why Kotlin complains

> error: unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
> **public inline fun <T, R : Any> Array<out TypeVariable(T)>.mapIndexedNotNull(transform: (index: Int, TypeVariable(T)) -> TypeVariable(R)?): List<TypeVariable(R)> defined in kotlin.collections**
> public inline fun  CharSequence.mapIndexedNotNull(transform: (index: Int, Char) -> TypeVariable(R)?): List<TypeVariable(R)> defined in kotlin.text
> public inline fun <T, R : Any> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.mapIndexedNotNull(transform: (index: Int, TypeVariable(T)) -> TypeVariable(R)?): List<TypeVariable(R)> defined in kotlin.collections
> public fun <T, R : Any> Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>.mapIndexedNotNull(transform: (index: Int, TypeVariable(T)) -> TypeVariable(R)?): Sequence<TypeVariable(R)> defined in kotlin.sequences
> positionValuePairs = nums.mapIndexedNotNull { index, value ->

my conditional returns either a pair if the value is nonzero or null, and mapNotIndexed aggregates the non null pairs; `nums` is an `IntArray`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [this](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-indexed-not-null.html) the function `mapIndexedNotNull` is defined as an extension on two classes:

- Array
- Iterable

But you are using [IntArray](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/05896a42da04620a2e8ca35e952ff31c3c48aa9d/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Arrays.kt#L234) which does not extend from any of the classes above.

I changed your code to the following and it works:

```
val nums: Array<Int> = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)

var positionValuePairs : List<Pair<Int, Int>> = listOf()

positionValuePairs = nums.mapIndexedNotNull { index: Int, value: Int ->
    if (value != 0) index to value else null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also split the call to `mapIndexedNotNull` into a call to `mapIndexed` an `filterNotNull()` like so:

```kotlin
val nums: IntArray

private val positionValuePairs: List<Pair<Int, Int>>

init {
    positionValuePairs = nums.mapIndexed { index: Int, value: Int ->
        if (value != 0) index to value else null
    }.filterNotNull()
}
```

This is functionally equivalent, while retaining the possibility to have `nums` as an `IntArray`.

Answer (score 0):

A definition of `mapIndexedNotNull` for `intArray` is unfortunately missing from the stdlib, but you can define it yourself:

```
inline fun <R> IntArray.mapIndexedNotNull(transform: (index: Int, value: Int) -> R?): List<R> =
    buildList {
        this@mapIndexedNotNull.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
            transform(index, value)?.let { add(it) }
        }
    }
```